# Conditional rendering JSX

Tags: reactjs

I have some lines of JSX that I want to show/hide when I click on a button.

I have initialized the state as such :

```
const [shown, setShown] = useState(true);
```

And this is the JSX :

```
      <div className="question--section">
        <div className="question--count">
          <span>Question {props.class[currentQuestion].id} </span>
          <h1>{props.class[currentQuestion].questionText}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I have tried to to do this :

```
{shown ? (
     <div className="question--section">
        <div className="question--count">
          <span>Question {props.class[currentQuestion].id} </span>
          <h1>{props.class[currentQuestion].questionText}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>) :
       (<div>Empty</div>)}
```

It doesn't work. How should I approach this? ( Switching the state should hide/show the JSX)

The whole component :

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const Quiz = (props) => {
  const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);

  const [shown, setShown] = useState(true);
  
  const handleAnswerButtonClick = () => {
    if (currentQuestion + 1 < props.class.length) {
      setCurrentQuestion((prevQuestion) => prevQuestion + 1);
    } else {
      alert("End of the quiz!");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="container quiz--container">
      <button>Κεφάλαιο 1</button>
      {shown ? (
      <div>
        <h1>Κεφάλαιο {props.id}</h1>
        <div className="question--section">
          <div className="question--count">
            <span>Question {props.class[currentQuestion].id} </span>
            <h1>{props.class[currentQuestion].questionText}</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="answer-section">
          {props.class[currentQuestion].answers.map((answer) => (
            <button onClick={handleAnswerButtonClick}>{answer.answerText}</button>
          ))}
        </div>) : 
        (<div>Empty</div>)}
  
    </div>
  );
};

export default Quiz;
```

Comment: can you post the larger component so we can see how the state change is happening?

Comment: Im currently just changing it manually, i will handle that with an onClick when manual switching the state works!

Comment: the condition block you have in the question should work in theory. that's why we need to see the rest of the component

Comment: you have to show how you "manually" set shown to true and false and when

Comment: I added the whole component. When I say manually, I mean I type false instead of true in the state initialization.

Comment: inside `handleAnswerButtonClick` callback, *setShown* to false. `setShown(false)`

Comment: _"It doesn't work."_ -- it would be helpful if you could elaborate on this.  Does it fail to render completely?  Always render one but not both conditions?  Always render both conditions?  Some other outcome?

Comment: The problem seemed to be really silly, I apologize! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing `</div>` before the `:`.

It should be this:

```
<div className="container quiz--container">
      <button>Κεφάλαιο 1</button>
      {shown ? (
      <div>
        <h1>Κεφάλαιο {props.id}</h1>
        <div className="question--section">
          <div className="question--count">
            <span>Question {props.class[currentQuestion].id} </span>
            <h1>{props.class[currentQuestion].questionText}</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="answer-section">
          {props.class[currentQuestion].answers.map((answer) => (
            <button onClick={handleAnswerButtonClick}>{answer.answerText}</button>
          ))}
        </div>
        </div>) : 
        (<div>Empty</div>)}
    </div>
```

Comment: that seemed to be it, Im very new, apologies!

Comment: A good IDE (code editor) will help you prevent these kinds of mistakes. I can recommend VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `handleAnswerButtonClick` callback, setShown to false or reverse it.

```
const handleAnswerButtonClick = () => {
  setShown(false)
  // or
  setShown(!shown)
  ...    
}
```